# use a variable value in an expression?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say that I have many resource files: `a.resx`, `b.resx` and `c.resx`

and I use it like this:

```
groupSettingsLogin.Caption = Resources.a.login_caption;
```

or

```
groupSettingsLogin.Caption = Resources.b.login_caption;
```

If I have a global variable public String ResourceName and I set this at start at a certain value:

```
MyGlobalVariables.ResourceName = "a";
```

then can I somehow refer to the resource dynamically as:

```
groupSettingsLogin.Caption = Resources."MyGlobalVariables.ResourceName".login_caption;
```

I know the above line is not correct but is there a way to to something like this?
Or if not is there an alternative way for it?

Comment: Are you trying to add localization to your program?

Comment: Why not have `MyGlobalVariables.Resources = Resources.a;` then `groupSettingsLogin.Caption = MyGlobalVariables.Resources.login_caption;`?

Comment: Have you looked into lower level API like [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.100).aspx)? (since it is not clear what you are trying to achieve it is hard to get more specific advice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("YourNamespace." + MyGlobalVariables.ResourceName, Type.GetType("YourNamespace." + MyGlobalVariables.ResourceName).Assembly);
var login_caption = resourceManager.GetString("login_caption", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I've checked this works fine. Previous answer was incorrect

Comment: a.resx and b.resx are resource files. What is the type for these? Thank you

Comment: @starhu, in a.Designer.cs and b.Designer.cs you can see code, that describes this types. Reflection isn't suitable because there are static properties and it's impossible create base class for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// MyGlobalVariables.Resources is `dynamic`
MyGlobalVariables.Resources = Resources.a; 

groupSettingsLogin.Caption = MyGlobalVariables.Resources.login_caption;
```

Comment: When I use:

MyGlobalVariables.Resources = Resources.a; -> I get the message Error 1 'Resources.a' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 0):

Look into the generated code. There you can see how it itself accesses the underlying data. Should be very easy. Single method call. There's no magic underneath the generated properties. They are a thin facade. I once looked but I don't remember what's there.